# How to build a static version of the pcap library for Arm Linux

Tags: c, linux, arm, cross-compiling, libpcap

I saw libpcap here https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap?files=1

I have compiler for arm linux.

How can I build libpcap to `a file` so I can statically link to this lib in my project?

I didn't find MakeFile for Arm.

Comment: arm64 package https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpcap0.8-dev ... Contains `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a` ... Depends on https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpcap0.8 ... Building from source : `./configure` (for arm) to get a Makefile.

Comment: @Knud Larsen sorry I didn't understand you, how can I achive a file for using libpcap for Arm?

Comment: If you have something to add to your question, a comment is not the right place. Instead, please edit your original question. .... »» archive a file «« : That's a new question. And it's not quite clear why you ask. "Archive" is a broad term.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 86_64 or later, assuming bison and flex were installed, and [gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz?revision=fed31ee5-2ed7-40c8-9e0e-474299a3c4ac&la=en&hash=76DAF56606E7CB66CC5B5B33D8FB90D9F24C9D20) was downloaded and extracted into the `/opt` directory, a possible procedure for cross-compiling the latest version from scratch would be:

```
wget https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/archive/libpcap-1.9.1.tar.gz
tar zxf libpcap-1.9.1.tar.gz
cd libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf- CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=$(pwd)/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf- CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc make install
```

The libraries and include files will be installed in `libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf`:

```
ls -gG  -a libpcap-1.9.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/include libpcap-1.9.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib
libpcap-1.9.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/include:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 4096 Feb  6 13:07 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 4096 Feb  6 13:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Feb  6 13:07 pcap
-rw-r--r-- 1 2294 Feb  6 13:07 pcap-bpf.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 2226 Feb  6 13:07 pcap.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 2024 Feb  6 13:07 pcap-namedb.h

libpcap-1.9.1-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib:
total 2108
drwxr-xr-x 3    4096 Feb  6 13:07 .
drwxrwxr-x 6    4096 Feb  6 13:07 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1199090 Feb  6 13:07 libpcap.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      12 Feb  6 13:07 libpcap.so -> libpcap.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Feb  6 13:07 libpcap.so.1 -> libpcap.so.1.9.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1  942752 Feb  6 13:07 libpcap.so.1.9.1
drwxr-xr-x 2    4096 Feb  6 13:07 pkgconfig
```

I hope this helps.

Just a remainder: Flex and Bison can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison
```